# Finding the definition of an object in a VB web-user-control

Tags: vb.net, webusercontrol

I have an ascx.vb file with a function that starts off like this:

```
Sub buildlist()
    repcaldatelist.Visible = True

    ...
End Sub
```

I'm just trying to figure out what `repcaldatelist` is.  When I use VS's "Go To Definition", it gives me a popup saying "The definition of the object is hidden."  Using "Go To Implementation" does nothing.

I see the corresponding .ascx file with this line:

```
<asp:repeater ID="repcaldatelist" runat="server">
```

and I see how `repcaldatelist` is databound to it, so that page can display its data.

But what I'm trying to understand is, where does `repcaldatelist` come from?  I want to see where it's initialized and what its type is.

I know this is probably really basic but I'm new to VB / Web User Controls and haven't had any luck searching for this online thus far.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: `ID="repcaldatelist"` means that's the ID of the Repeater control. It doesn't have anything to do with data binding. So in your .vb file, repcaldatelist is an object of type Repeater - the ID in the ascx/html translates into a variable name in the VB.

Comment: @ADyson I know it doesn't have anything to do with the data-binding, I was just mentioning that I see in the code where the data-binding is happening.  I was just trying to clarify what I know and what I don't know.

Comment: @ADyson so you knew it's of type Repeater because of the `<asp:repeater` part?

Comment: Exactly. And probably if you hover over the variable in the .vb file in Visual Studio it would tell you that as well.

Comment: re the databinding, you stated "I see how repcaldatelist is databound to it, so that page can display its data" I thought you meant that the fact that the names matched between the ascx and the .vb meant that databinding was taking place. It wasn't clear that there was other (unshown) code relating to databinding that you'd spotted :-)

Comment: P.S. Go To Definition / Implementation don't work because the Repeater class is part of the .NET framework, and it's closed-source - just a DLL on your machine. Therefore there's no source code or definition you can view. You just have access to its public API as defined by the docs (and should be available in intellisense as well)

Comment: @ADyson thanks so much.  If you want to mark your comments down as the answer then I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID="repcaldatelist" means that's the ID of the Repeater control. So in your .vb file, repcaldatelist is an object of type Repeater - the ID in the ascx/html translates into a variable name in the VB. If you hover over the variable in the .vb file in Visual Studio it should tell you the type as well.

Go To Definition / Implementation don't work because the Repeater class is part of the .NET framework, and it's closed-source - just a DLL on your machine. Therefore there's no source code or definition you can view. You just have access to its public API as defined by the docs (and should be available in intellisense as well).